# La Guardia to Hampton Bays

Tags: trains, airport-transfer, new-york-city, lga

I am arriving into La Guardia just before 8 pm on Thursday evening and want to reach Hampton Bays.  Train, uber, ideas?

Comment: The next-to-last LIRR train leaves Jamaica at 8:53, which seems tight.  The following train is not until 1:10 AM and will get you to Hampton Bays about 3 AM :-(

Comment: Are you arriving on a domestic or international flight, with or without luggage?  If a domestic flight without luggage, it doesn't sound too tight.

Comment: @gerrit: LGA doesn't have customs/immigration facilities, so all arriving flights are either domestic or come from a preclearance airport, which is effectively the same for present purposes.  Still, it takes time to get off the plane and out of the airport, and Google predicts 30+ minutes to get from LGA to Jamaica by car.  Any significant delays and you're in trouble.  (There are closer LIRR stations but then you have to change at Jamaica; it doesn't seem better.)

Comment: @NateEldredge "it doesn't seem better": There's a train from Woodside at 8:33 that connects very comfortably with the 8:53 at Jamaica.  It's a 10- to 20-minute taxi ride, less than half the distance to Jamaica.  The reduced risk of delays and the lower taxi fare probably do make this option rather better than a taxi to Jamaica.  (It's also about a half-hour bus ride from the airport to Woodside station, but, unless the flight is early, the chance of missing the train would be rather too great for my taste.)

Answer (score 2):

You could go by bus with [Hampton Jitney](https://reservations.hamptonjitney.com/hjmobile/). However, you will need to take a taxi or Uber from LGA to their bus station “Queens Airport Connection - Eastbound” which is not far from LGA. See the website for more details.

Comment: The only bus after 8 PM is at 10:35 PM, but if it's not possible to make the LIRR train at 8:53 this would definitely be better than taking the 1:10 AM train.